Tricking a Mitsubishi MR SLIM outdoor unit to run without the outdoor fan?
Our AC just died at the start of a heatwave! When it starts up, the the compressor turns on but the outdoor fan does not start spinning. Then after 60 seconds the compressor turns off and it gives an outdoor fan error code. Note that it does this even if I keep the condenser coil with a fan or hose water, so it seems the compressor is not turning off because of thermal or high side pressure safety. Instead, the control board is seeing that the fan is not turning via the optical sensor, and then is it turning off the compressor.
I have not found a way to get a replacement for at least 4 days and so I would love to find a way to get the working. If I could just get the control board to keep the compressor running then I could just ziptie a big box fan over the coils and everything would work great.
There are lots of dip switches on the controller PCB but I can not find any documentation for them.
Any ideas?  Thanks!




it could be just the fan start capacitor, replace it

@Traveler this is a brushless DC motor so no start capacitor. :)

This is going to be a control board failure or a fan motor failure. You could try spinning the fan hard to see if that clears it temporarily, but I wouldn't hold out much hope. The control board is going to watch for feedback from the fan motor.

@kmj All agreed. Unfortunately I am literally on an island with no access to parts, in the middle of a heat wave. :)  I just wish there way some way to tell/trick the control PCB to "keep running the compressor even if you do not see feedback from the fan motor".

After much diagnosing, I found that the motor windings and opto-detectors were good but the voltages coming out of the control board to the fan motor were flakey when the motor was connected. Looking at the schematic...

...it seems that all current going to that motor goes though fuse F931. Checking that fuse, it seemed that the contacts were quite corroded...

...which makes sense since this is on an island near the sea and the fuse holders are not conformally coated like the rest of the board.
I removed the fuse and cleaned the contacts with a nail file and the fan started working again and cooling was restored.

Well done! Nice sleuthing. Be sure to click the check mark so others know that this has a solution.
